# Serve multiple entry points with webpack dev server

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I've got multiple entry points being generated with outputs successfully but what I'm not too sure on is if there is a way with the webpack dev server to serve these multiple entry points and somehow be able to work on them all at the same time?

Here is my basic setup right now, is there a way I can get webpack dev server to somehow serve these on different ports maybe or by changing the URL serve the different entry points?

I've tried changing the port number on one of the apps but it doesn't seem to run a server with that port, which I kind of figured it wouldn't

```
  entry: {
   dashboard: [
      "webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000",
      "webpack/hot/only-dev-server",
      paths.appIndexJs
    ],
    display: [
      "webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000",
      "webpack/hot/only-dev-server",
      paths.displayJs
    ]
  },
  output: {
    pathinfo: true,
    filename: "static/js/[name].js",
    chunkFilename: "static/js/[name].chunk.js",
    publicPath: publicPath,
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info =>
      path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, "/")
  },
```